# Single Android Application Getting Push Notifications From Multiple Firebase Accounts

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developed a single Android application which should get push notifications from multiple firebase accounts.

I integrated a default firebase account to my application and i can get push notifications from that firebase account without any problem.

To get push notifications from multiple firebase accounts can I follow these steps?

1) Android application will get SenderId s of firebase accounts that will send push notifications.

2) Android application should call the function below for each senderId. This will authorize each senderId to send push notifications to this application.

```
 String token1 = FirebaseInstanceId.getToken (senderId1, "FCM");

 String token2 = FirebaseInstanceId.getToken (senderId2, "FCM");
```

3) Android application will send token1 to the server associated with senderId1, token2 to associated 
   with senderId2.

4) Than, firebaseServer with senderId1 can send push notification to my application by using token1 and firebaseServer with senderId2 can send push notification to my application by using token2.

5) Android application should periodically check for tokens validity by function below in case of change. If Android application detects a change, it will send the new token to it's server.

```
 String token1 = FirebaseInstanceId.getToken (senderId1, "FCM");

 String token2 = FirebaseInstanceId.getToken (senderId2, "FCM");
```

Did I understand the usage of FCM with multiple accounts correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of, yes. You need to keep both tokens alive, so most likely you will have to connect to both accounts and keep checking those tokens. 
This should help you too
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#receiving-messages-from-multiple-senders